# Setting up Google Analytics 4 for an Electron App

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, electron, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm currently trying to set up some sort of analytics solution for an Electron app that I'm working on.  I'm currently leaning toward using a solution like this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-google-analytics4

However, I'm unsure how to set up a data stream for an electron app.  I've been told to "treat it as a regular website", but my assumption (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that GA4 will be listening to the URL that I've provided to it in the data stream.  Being that I'm working with a desktop app with no URL, I don't think that this is correct.  I've tried setting up the data stream with a random URL but I'm getting no events going through from the app.

Anyone have any insight on how to get this going?  I will also happily take any suggestions for alternative analytics solutions.  Thanks so much in advance.